# H2 Group By when selecting in to an object using truncate function

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

with JPA (provided by Hibernate) and H2 I'm trying to do this.

```
    String query = "select NEW domain.Activity(count(*), cast (truncate(startDateTime) as timestamp),type) from Event group by 2,3 "; 

    TypedQuery<Activity> jQuery = em.createQuery(query, Activity.class);
```

Problem is H2 won't allow me to group by "2" because it's the result of a function (you can do this in other languages so it wasn't so far-fetched)

The only way I can find to do it is by replacing '2' with the Alias Hibernate generates (which seems like a really bad idea) I can't give the column my own alias becasue Hibernate ignores that, so is there a solution to this using H2?

For clarity:

```
    String query = "select NEW domain.Activity(count(*), cast (truncate(startDateTime) as timestamp),type) from Event group by col_1_0_,3 "; 

    TypedQuery<Activity> jQuery = em.createQuery(query, Activity.class);
```

Does work as expected because 'col_1_0_' is the Alias hibernate is applying to the truncate column.

Comment: "TRUNCATE" is invalid JPQL, as is "count(*)"

Comment: Yes but they work as they are registered keywords when using H2 or something.

Comment: It does work. You aren't reading the question properly, and are needlessly confusing the situation. i appreciate you trying to help though. Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate that it's non portable, I very much wish it was, but JPQL doesn't support what i want to do.  H2 does, previously I had postgres doing this and it was fine, of course the non portability is I am now paying the price for, but the fact is no matter how much we bang on about portability being so amazing, we just are not there yet. No 2 databases offer the same set of functionality and each provides useful efficient features that are often more efficient to use than just iterating through result sets to achieve the same thing.

Comment: My question is a simple one, is there a way to get it to work the way I want. I am not asking for a breakdown of why I'm failing at life an you are winning, just hoping for a quick fix to a dirty problem. I do know several other ways of getting to the same result, and I know the portable way to do it would be to select my entire table and generate my own results but I have concerns about efficiency in large datasheets and I want to use the power of the database to alleviate this concerns. Not to mention save me development time.